# How to find which group was captured in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression `/(q)|([zZ])|(E)/`.
My question is, how to get WHICH group was matched.

So, if I do
`"ZqE".replace(/(q)|([zZ])|(E)/g, /* ??? */)`
How do I get the output "213"?

Comment: Your pattern uses an alternation, which matches either q zZ or E. Do you mean `[zZ]qE` ?

Comment: No, I want to match any of the characters, and find which group did it.

Comment: q is group 1, Zz is group 2 and E is group 3 as defined in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, the group which matches will hold the value remaining one will be undefined

```js
let mapper = {
  'g1': 1,
  'g2': 2,
  'g3': 3
}

let final = "ZqE".replace(/(q)|([zZ])|(E)/g, (m, g1, g2, g3) => {
  return g1 !== undefined && mapper['g1'] || g2 !== undefined && mapper['g2'] || g3 !== undefined && mapper['g3']
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `result` array from [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to figure out which group was matched:

```js
let re = /(q)|([zZ])|(E)/g;
while (result = re.exec('ZqE')) {
    console.log(result.findIndex((v, i) => i && typeof(v) !== 'undefined'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern you specify 3 capturing groups which are numbered from 1 to 3.

If you want to get "213" and you know that you want to convert q to 1, zZ to 2 and E to 3, as an alternative you could do that by checking the values of the match using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
let result = "ZqE".replace(/[ZzEq]/g, function(m) {
  if (m.toLowerCase() === 'z') return 2;
  if (m === 'q') return 1;
  if (m === 'E') return 3;
});
console.log(result);
```